# Freeing xmlChar pointers after xmlTextReaderGetAttribute()

Tags: c++, c, free, libxml2

I was using `xmlTextReaderGetAttribute` (from [xmlsoft.org](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html)) successfully before, but the API documentation requires that I deallocate the returned `xmlChar*`. Now my app crashes on the second (the first passes null) call to `free()`, shown below:

```
xmlTextReaderPtr reader = null;
xmlChar *attribVal = null;
//blah...
if (xmlTextReaderAttributeCount(reader) > 0) {
    free((attribVal));

attribVal = xmlTextReaderGetAttribute(reader, (const xmlChar*)"super-Attrib");
if (xmlStrcasecmp(attribVal, (const xmlChar*)"monoMega-Attrib") == 0) {
    free((attribVal));
```

my project is in C++ but the libxml2 and all examples from [xmlsoft.org](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html) use standard C.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but why are you writing `free(())` with two sets of parens??
What is your project crashing with (segfault?) and can you put prints right before and after that second free just to make sure it is crashing there?

Comment: @Dan, I am stepping through it with gdb, it is crashing there. The doube parens (()) are to cast `const` ness or to void *. I had them in a function until I found it was crashing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `xmlFree()` instead of `free()` directly:

```
xmlTextReaderPtr reader = null; 
xmlChar *attribVal = null; 
//blah... 
if (xmlTextReaderAttributeCount(reader) > 0)
{ 
    attribVal = xmlTextReaderGetAttribute(reader, BAD_CAST "super-Attrib"); 
    if (attribVal)
    {
        ...
        xmlFree(attribVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to delay-load `xmlFree` despite being defined and redefined in the `globals.h`?

Comment: Depending on which defines you use when compiling libxml, `xmlFree` is either a macro that calls `__xmlFree()` and then dereferences the function pointer it returns, or it is a function pointer variable that points to either `xmlMemFree()` or `free()` by default.  So you will have to take into account what `xmlFree` actually is, and in the latter case you can then delay-load whichever function it is actually pointing to (or just point it to your own memory function).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Most comprehensive answer I've gotten on this question. I'll try it when I get home.